# I am trying to redirect to paypal from my site http:\\www.abc.com and it doesn't work

Tags: redirect, paypal

I am trying to redirect to paypal from my site http:\www.abc.com and it doesn't work and shows message like To help protect the security of information you enter into this website, the publisher of this content does not allow it to be displayed in a frame.

Anyone can tell what is this issue for?

Comment: How are you trying to do this? Show some sample code.

Comment: when user come on my site and choose product and when he click on check out to give payment, then he will be redirect to appropriate page.

In that page I put up a form having below code:

    <form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" id="Form2">
    some parameters which i need to send to paypal is here.                                        
    </form>

When I was working on it, at that time it runs good without any issue. As sson as my work complete and I have make my site live I got this issue during sending command to Paypal

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code example directly from the PayPal Developer Site:

[For PayPal Button Manager API Overview click here](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/button-manager/integration-guide/NVP/ButtonMgrOverview)

```
<form target="paypal" action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="19218">
<table>
<tr><td><input type="hidden" name="on0" value="Color">Color</td></tr><tr><td><select name="os0">
<option value="Red">Red $10.00
<option value="Blue">Blue $8.00
<option value="Green">Green $12.00
</select> </td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="hidden" name="on1" value="Size">Size</td></tr><tr><td><select name="os1">
<option value="Small">Small
<option value="Large">Large
</select> </td></tr>
</table>
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<input type="image" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_cart_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```